# How can Redis be optimized for storing lists of GUIDs?

Tags: redis, node-redis

We are using Redis to store shuffled decks of cards. A card is represented by a 20 character GUID, and a deck is an array of shuffled card GUIDs. The primary operations called on the Deck list is LLEN (length) and LPOP (pop). The only time that we push to a deck is a) when the deck is initially created and b) when the deck runs out of cards and is re-shuffled (which happens rarely). Currently, the length of a deck varies from 10 to 700 items.

What type of memory optimizations can be made in Redis for this sort of problem?  Is there any sort of setting we can configure to reduce the memory overhead, or optimize how (zip)list data types are used?

Related Article: http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion would be to use 8byte unsigned integers as your identifier key instead of guids, that saves you several bytes per entry in memory, and increases overall performance of any database including redis you are using.

In case you want to go with guid, and considering the size of list and the operations you are doing on the list.
You can tune the redis defaults to suit your need :
Redis defaults :

```
list-max-ziplist-entries 512
list-max-ziplist-value 64
```

You can change this to :

```
list-max-ziplist-entries 1024 #to accomodate your 700 cards list
list-max-ziplist-value 256 # to accomodate your 20 byte guids
```

YMMV, hence you need to benchmark redis with both settings, for storage as well as read/write performance with your sample data.

Comment: Thanks we will deploy this shortly! Going to benchmark the change as well and see how much effect it has.